# How to Upgrade from laravel 5.2 to 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I want to update Laravel to the latest version 5.4.
But direct migration is not given in [laravel migration guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade), so first I am trying to migrate it to laravel 5.3.
My project is working on a 5.2 laravel version and trying to upgrade it.

I have updated `composer.json` as guided into the documentation of laravel migration guide.
And run command `composer update` on the command line.

I am getting the following error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Loading composer repositories with package information
```

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.1
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.1 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.2 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.3 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.4 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.5 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.6 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.7 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.4.8 requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.9].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16,
v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.31, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.
3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html ~5.4 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.4, v5.4.1, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8].
```

What extra changes do I need to make in composer.json to make the update work?

** UPDATE:**

This is `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.4",
        "kepex/laravel-crud-generator": "^0.1.4",
        "watson/bootstrap-form": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "danvuquoc/laravel-kraken": "1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.0",
        "danielboendergaard/phantom-pdf": "^1.2",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy": "^0.4.3",
        "wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "0.12.2.3",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5",
        "eluceo/ical": "^0.11.0",
        "jurosh/pdf-merge": "dev-master",
        "torann/geoip": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "roumen/sitemap": "dev-master",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "rackspace/php-opencloud": "dev-master",
         "ellisthedev/laravel-5-robots": "~0.1.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1",
        "matthiasmullie/minify": "^1.3",
        "lullabot/amp": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*|3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*|3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["database"],
        "files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": ["tests/TestCase.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": ["php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""],
        "post-create-project-cmd": ["php artisan key:generate"],
        "post-install-cmd": ["Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall", "php artisan optimize"],
        "post-update-cmd": ["Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate", "php artisan optimize"]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to update the dompdf package from 0.6.1 to latest version.
`"dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8"` update the version in your composer.json

Comment: No luck mate. I tried this too.

Comment: Still getting same error? or other package dependencies version problem?

Comment: I have updated error log message, please check. Those errors are gone. Now some left

Comment: change to "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3", as v5.4 requires laravel framework v5.4

Comment: still no luck mate

Comment: You want to upgrade to 5.3 or 5.4?

Comment: Updated my answer have you checked?

Comment: You can check these file diffs in order to upgrade to 5.5:
https://qiita.com/michimani/items/560e439fcb26a37bca0b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I end up using advantage of [link](https://laravelshift.com/) as these people integrated everything possible. Just minor changes from our side, that too they will mention in the log when they upgrade latest version of laravel. Its paid thing, but one time investment to save time worth it.

Answer (score 4):

I migrated from Laravel 5.2 to 5.6.3 Here are my steps:

Firstly, you need to update providers **app/Providers/{EventServiceProvider, RouteServiceProvider}.php**.
Their boot() methods shouldn't take arguments:

```
     ...
-    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
+    public function boot()
     {
-        parent::boot($events);
+        parent::boot();
     }
     ...
```

Secondly, update your composer.json. Here is my default configuration:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "~2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "symfony/thanks": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Then run `composer update` or `php composer.phar update`

**Replace your App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php from original repository.**

**Move your routes from app/routes/web.php to routes/web.php** (initially, you may also want to copy the routes from original Laravel)

**Replace your controllers for Authentication from original Laravel repository in folder app/Http/Controllers/Auth**

Comment out your old auth routes and add `Auth::routes();` in web.php routes file ([more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700000/4567218)).

Add `config/hashing.php` from original repository.

Run `php artisan config:cache` to reset the cache.

Finally, update your DB structure `php artisan migrate --seed` and run the app `php artisan serve`

**[Original Laravel Repository](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)**

Comment: you we don't need to do more to migrate from 5.2 to 5.6 today ? I'm looking for a way to do that ? I'm reading update from 5.2 to 5.3 and there are a lot of steps contrary to your method ? thank you

Comment: Could you provide a link to the article?
In my case, I successfully migrated by following the steps described above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this:

You have to update first LaravelCollective [html package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) as well.

In your `composer.json`, replace:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

with:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.4.*"
```

Comment: No luck mate same error is coming. But one thing I noticed, error lines has been reduced

Answer (score 0):

You have to update first barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package.

In your composer.json change:

first change

`"laravel/framework": "5.3.*"` to the previous one

and then change

from

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.6.1",
```

to

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
```

and then hit `composer update` command

and then change `"laravel/framework": "5.3.*"` and again hit

```
`composer update`
```

command

Comment: Do one thing first change your  "laravel/framework": "5.3.*" to old one and then hit composer update command. so it will update "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf" package first without any error and then change  "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"

Comment: Actually I want to update 5.2 to 5.4 but direction migration not given in guide. So I am first trying to migrate from 5.2 to 5.3 and then 5.3 to 5.4. If first one works

Comment: let just remove laravelcollective/html": "~5.4", "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0", these two lines and then hit composer update.

Comment: It looked like it works but, at last it throw 
 [ErrorException]
 Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot() should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935130/i-used-composer-to-upgrade-to-laravel-5-3-which-broke-it getting? Check out the upgrade guide

Comment: You may remove the arguments from the boot method on the EventServiceProvider, RouteServiceProvider, and AuthServiceProvider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148011/discussion-between-rahul-meshram-and-sr).